# disable url action without disabling mouseover text

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to use something similar to `pointer-events: none` to disable *only* the hyperlink and *not* the mouseover text?

For example, suppose I have:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="mouseover text" style="pointer-events: none">link text</a>
```

Then the link is disabled, but the mouseover text is also disabled. I want to know how to just disable the link, while keeping the mouseover text active.

Comment: If you don't want it to be a link, don't use one. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could just add an `onclick` with `return false;` [example](http://jsfiddle.net/chriz123/pbjp55ga/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replicate this using `Javascript`, just simply take out the `style` and add `onclick`.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="mouseover text" onclick="return false;">link text</a>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chriz123/pbjp55ga/)

I would not suggest doing this, instead, I would suggest styling a `<span>` to look like a link, with a `title` to get the tooltip effect you are after.

[Here is an example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/chriz123/pbjp55ga/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I have several dozen links that I am using JQuery to assign different urls and mouseover texts to according to their class. There are one or two that don't have active urls (yet) and I wanted a simple way to disable just the link part after the fact (without changing the code of how all of the links are handled), so that when these eventually have urls I can just delete those extra lines.

Comment: @Gabe No problem mate, the first method should work fine for just a temporary thing. Good luck with your project sir!

Answer (score 1):

Like this. Javascript will stop the link working when you click it. However the title is still shown when hovering over it

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="mouseover text" onClick="function(){return false;}">link text</a>
```

This is not really very good coding though. If you don't want a link, then don't have one. If you want he effect of basically a tooltip then create a tooltip instead.